# Determining the voltage of a network branch

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, basic, network

**[NOTE-This is a not a homework problem and i am not asking anyone to solve it]**
Recently I have been simulating some basic circuit analysis problems in a simulator to get a better feel of the topic.Today i came across this problem----[image]

Now the problem that i faced is that i was unable to determine the voltage of the highlighted branch by virtually analyzing.But the voltage of the branch can be found out easily by K.C.L Law.Is there any shortcuts to this problem?Am i missing any concepts.I am really confused.Which voltage source will control the branch voltage?I simulated the circuit below is the observation--[image]
1)In the above picture the voltage of the branch equals to the voltage source A)Voltage of the branch doesn't get affected when B is increased.Why?

So my two questions are-------------------------

1)**Voltage of the branch doesn't get affected when B is increased.Why?**

2)**Do the voltage source A really controls the branch voltage?As shown by the simulator.**

3)**Am i missing any concepts?I can solve this problem by applying KCL but can the voltage of the branch be determined by virtually analyzing(According to the sim we can determine the voltage by finding out the voltage of A,is that observation reliable?)That info will be useless if the network completely changes so i need a concrete explanation.**

simulation with the ground and according to the first image---
[image]

Comment: Why is the middle resistor 1 ohm? Why did you originally have a 30 volts source then change to a 40 volts source? Why isn't there an earth reference point on your sim circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka took 40 to show the dependence of branch voltage on the voltage A i kept on increasing A the branch V increases at the same rate.it should be 5 ohm can be changed but  the branch voltage remains the same.No ground for simplicity,with ground the branch voltage increases doesn't changes anything i think.

Comment: @Andyaka even with 5ohm the branch voltage doesnt changes so for 1 ohm so i didnt changed it.Voltage of lower branch changes just that.

Comment: Something wrong with simulation. Missing ground maybe..

Comment: @ParanJyotiBharali You are not listening and not looking what mistakes are in your simulation. Do you know what the letter "k" signifies? "No ground for simplicity"? No ground = stupidity.

Comment: @Andyaka i am changing wait

Comment: @Andyaka k for kilo notation?or am i missing something else?

Comment: @Andyaka what is the problem without ground?I didnt understand that part.Why ground is needed?

Comment: @Andyaka edited the question with the image..Please do help.

Comment: Ground is the measurement reference point for other voltages. It is 0 volts. You cannot specify any node voltage without dictating the node that is regarded as 0 volts. 1 kohm does not equal 1 ohm

Comment: @Andyaka do look at the new image i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Andyaka do look at the new image i posted

Yes, that is what you should get (my simulation): -

[image]

If you analyse it you will see that V2 branch takes zero current.

All your other errors are because you had used the wrong voltage source for V1, had forgotten about adding a 0 volt reference point and you were using ohms instead of kohms for the middle resistor.

Comment: ooh i see,so a ground is must to get the correct value of a branch?without that we get wrong values at the node/branch.

Comment: Voltage = potential difference and, if you don't specify a reference potential then voltages on each node are unclear.

Comment: Is there a problem with the simulator?The result it produced is not reliable--it showed that  branch voltage increases proportionally with voltage source A?So that assumption is completely misleading and wrong.

Comment: I have never used that sim (Falstad?) so I can't say but your first sim result (40 volts at top and 34.98 volts at bottom) is probably because you had no ground point.

Comment: Yeah Falstad ..and thanks this really helped me a lot